# MaxStringContentLength maximum size

Tags: c#, maxstringcontentlength

I am getting this message when I tried to pass a largestring on my webservice.

"The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'SetPropertyValue'. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 174, position 19."

There is my service binding on client configuration file:

```
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IParamSvc" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
         openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
         maxBufferSize="63400320" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="63400320"
         messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="None"
          realm="" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
```

I've already set the client side values too.

Any ideas to solve my problem ?

Thank you.

Comment: I guess that you have tried this already? "This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader."

Comment: I changed the MaxStringContentLength value on client and server side. I did not try nothing more than that. I tried to do this steps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777114/fixing-maximum-length-quota-on-xmldictionaryreaderquotas-for-wcf-4-0-rest, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the client config?