# The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message

Tags: wcf

The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: Error in deserializing body of request message for operation 'PostTransaction'. The maximum string content length quota (8192) has been exceeded while reading XML data. This quota may be increased by changing the MaxStringContentLength property on the XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas object used when creating the XML reader. Line 52

Answer (score 1):

You need add this argument to your config, like

`<bindings> <webHttpBinding> <binding> <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="65535"/> </binding> </webHttpBinding> </bindings>`

Exaple from  this answer: [Fixing maximum length quota on XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas for WCF 4.0 REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6777114/fixing-maximum-length-quota-on-xmldictionaryreaderquotas-for-wcf-4-0-rest)